# Get llvm::Function size after MCJIT code generation

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

In LLVM, I'm able, via the MCJIT ExecutionEngine to get the function address of a compiled llvm::Function, but I don't know how to get its size in memory, is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no special method to get size of the memory occupied by certain function's machine code in Execution Engine memory. But you can collect  addresses with `getFunctionAddress` (for defined functions), reorder these addresses, and then calculate sizes (as a difference between every neighboring pair).